# CAShapeLayer disable antialiasing

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I'm making a "marching ants" selection frame with Core Animation Layers like in this post: [MARCHING ANTS WITH CORE ANIMATION](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/10/20/marching-ants-with-core-animation/).
But the only thing I don't like is the width of line in CAShapeLayer. I need the width to be exactly 1px, but because of antialiasing the line width is about 2 pixels and a little transparent.

Is there any way to turn off antialiasing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the docs, it looks like you're stuck with antialising:

> The CAShapeLayer class draws a cubic Bezier spline in its coordinate
>   space. The shape is composited between the layer's contents and its
>   first sublayer.
>
> **The shape will be drawn antialiased**, and whenever possible it will be
>   mapped into screen space before being rasterized to preserve
>   resolution independence. However, certain kinds of image processing
>   operations, such as CoreImage filters, applied to the layer or its
>   ancestors may force rasterization in a local coordinate space.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem, fortunately, I wandered around a bit more and found the CGContextSetShouldAntialias( GCContextRef, BOOL) function.  It turns out that the antialiasing was happening in the Graphics Context.

I tested this with a series of shape layers under a CALayer rendering into a bitmap context.
By default, I got the values I set in the range 100-130 ( bitmap values), and a bunch of lower numbers.  After setting CGContextSetShouldAlias( context, NO), I got just my values.

Comment: The method name is wrong (should be "CGContextSetShouldAntialias") but adding this gave an immediate 15% increase in performance in my app - Thanks!